# MySQL Select Multiple VALUES

Tags: mysql, select

Totally out of ideas here, could be needing a simple solution.

Basically my desired query is :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3,4
```

I want to select only the row which has ID 3 and 4, or maybe name "andy" and "paul"

Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Try `or`:

```
WHERE id = 3 or id = 4
```

Or the equivalent `in`:

```
WHERE id in (3,4)
```

Comment: And there in maybe a faster expression between those two solutions, but "WHERE id in (3,4)" is the most readable.

Comment: thanks, i end up using the first method. It didn't work at first because I used AND... lol . Is it possible to use LIKE in there? I mean WHERE name in ('%P%', '%A') will generate Paul, Peter, Andy, Ann

Comment: @Henson - you can use LIKE as "WHERE name like 'P%' or name like 'A%' "

Comment: @Henson: LIKE would work with OR, but not with IN.  For example `where name like 'A%' or name like 'B%'`

Answer (score 23):

Try this -

```
 select * from table where id in (3,4) or [name] in ('andy','paul');
```