# SQL query based on comma separated values condition?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Select Multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749933/mysql-select-multiple-values)

lets say i have a group of number like (3,2,5) the normal way i use to split them and searching mysql to get value is to split them using explode in PHP

EXAMPLE

```
$string = '3,4,5';
$array = explode(',',$string);
foreach($array as $value){
    $query = 'SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID = "'.$value.'"';
}
```

it work like this but it make the script extremely slow

i need now if there is away to split this string into the query it self and return the result without looping with PHP ?

Comment: are you executing that query inside the loop?

Comment: Bro, you should first read the basics.

Comment: Please tell me you're not actually just selecting the id from the table when you already have an array of ids...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IN`,

```
$string = '3,4,5';
$query = "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ($string)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not a `WHERE ... IN ...`?

```
select ID from TABLE where ID in (3,4,5)
```

Comment: because i didn't know about it im still mysql newbie :)

Comment: it's a standard sql feature. no worries either way. everyone had to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your $string variable is:

```
$string = '3,4,5';
```

Try to build your query as this:

```
$query = 'SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID in (".$string.")';
```

You don't need a loop for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN` operator.

Also, make sure to apply the proper escaping (in this case it shouldn't matter, but it does when fields are submitted via web request):

```
$string = '3,4,5';
$array = explode(',', $string);

// cast all array elements into integers
$numbers = join(',', array_map('intval', $array));

$query = "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ($numbers)";
```

Another fancy way is to use prepared statements:

```
$placeholders = join(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));
$query = "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ($placeholders)";
```

Then to perform the query you would bind the numbers like so (PDO example):

```
// prepare the query, looks like 'WHERE ID IN (?,?,?)'
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
// execute the query and pass the array values
$stmt->execute($array);
```