# Search for text in specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with category and title columns.

```
category     title
---------    ------
game         abcd
tech         567
tech         1234
game         efg
tech         abcd
```

I need all the rows with game as category, then select all the "game" rows that have '1234' or 'efg' or 'abcd' as title. Is there a way to do this with one single query?If not, what's the best solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Multiple VALUES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749933/mysql-select-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic SQL. I'd suggest you to go through some basic SQL tutorials first.

```
select *
from your_table
where category = 'game'
    and title in ('1234', 'efg', 'abcd')
```

Comment: what if i want to search where category equal to game or tech ? i tried with  "where category='game' or category='tech' and title...." but it returns anyway all the rows with game and tech without searching if those rows have the titles i want.

Comment: You can use  `IN` instead of many `OR`s - `where category in ('game', 'tech') and title in ('1234', 'efg', 'abcd')`