# In mysql how to passs multiple values with camma separated in where clause

Tags: mysql

```
select log_id as attendanceId,l.user_id as employeeId,l.log_date as attnInDate,emp.emp_name as 
employeeName,l.in_remarks as inRemarks,emp.dept_id as departmentId,fn_get_hr_dept_name(emp.dept_id) as 
departmentName, l.out_remarks as outRemarks,group_concat(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE '' END) AS logTimings,MIN(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE NULL END) inTime1,MAX(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE NULL END) inTime2,MAX(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE NULL END) outTime1,TIME_FORMAT(timediff(MAX(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE NULL END),MIN(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE NULL END)), '%H:%i') as workingHrsMonth

 from at_hr_logs_2017_October l,at_hr_emp emp where log_date=curdate() 
and l.user_id=emp.emp_code and emp.dept_id=5 and 6 group by user_id;
```

want to pass dept value like dept_id=5,6,7,8 like that

any solutions regarding this please ping me.

Comment: You might want to look at the `IN()` operator: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in. And you should consider checking the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749933/mysql-select-multiple-values)

Comment: Sample input and output would be invaluable right now.  I suspect that what you need goes beyond just using `WHERE IN (...)`, but I can't be certain until I see some data.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're talking about  `emp.dept_id = 5 and 6` in the **where** clause,
you will have to use 'IN' in this case.

Ex: emp.dept_id IN (5,6,7,8)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feed back as its working very fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas Feste said you can use IN operator.

Use

```
 where dept_id in (5,6,7,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
SELECT column1
FROM tablename          
WHERE column IN (val1, val2, val3);
```