# how to find out employees who have the required skills using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table Employee which has two columns:

```
empl_no   skill
========= =========================
1001      Java
1001      Python
1002      JavaScript
1003      C#
1003      Excel Macro
1001      C
```

How can I filter out the employee who have **ALL** of the listed skills 'Java', 'Python', 'C' using SQL Select statement?

Comment: Is this what you are searching for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3749940/4132369

Answer (score 4):

You can use a in clause and having

```
select empl_no
from my_table 
where skill in ( 'Java', 'Python', 'C' )
group by empl_no
having count(distinct skill) = 3
```

Comment: adding one assumption for above query that combination of empl_no and skill are unique in the table.

Comment: This serves my need.  However, is there any alternative Select statement?

Comment: I am not sure my table design is right for this kind of employee skill filtering search.  If the table design is alright, it seems that Anil's select statement is the only solution which uses 'group by ... having count(...)'.  Is that true?

Comment: @w2know The table design is correct and the use of having  (...) = 3 is the key for check that all the skill is related  to the user.. .. The having(disctinct  skill) in an enforcement for check that the number of skill match for avoid the case of duplicated skill in  skill  relation. anyway the concept remain the same   .. and last .. as Select statetement this is the only possible  ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this query.

```
SELECT empl_no FROM employee 
WHERE skill IN ( 'Java', 'Python', 'C' )
GROUP BY empl_no HAVING COUNT(skill)=3;
```