# SQL - how to pull multiple rows in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Lets say I have a simple table. Each row is a product getting shipped...with a unique `ID` number. I want a result of the `SELECT` fields for a set of 5 `ID` numbers... Is there a simpler way to return the five rows of data other than what I've done before?

Ideally I want to copy/paste a list of `ID`s in the `WHERE` clause like: `WHERE ID = 1, 19, 35, 70, 121`

```
SELECT ID, Shipping Date, Estimated_Ready_date FROM reportB 
WHERE ID = 1 or ID = 19 or ID = 35 or ID = 70 or ID = 121
```

Comment: The code can be simplified with IN: `WHERE ID IN (1, 19, 35, 70, 121)`

Comment: You can use `in`: `id in (1, 19, 35, 70, 121)`.

Comment: Please edit your Question to add a tag with your RDBMS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Select Multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749933/mysql-select-multiple-values)

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use below query,

```
SELECT ID, Shipping Date, Estimated_Ready_date FROM reportB 
WHERE ID IN (1, 19, 35, 70, 121);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Shipping Date, Estimated_Ready_date
FROM reportB
WHERE ID IN (1, 19, 35, 70, 121)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this :**

```
SELECT ID, Date d'expédition, Estimated_Ready_date
FROM reportB
WHERE ID IN (1,19,35,70,121)
```