# Mysql filter by multiply ids

Tags: mysql, join, filter

I can't finish writing query to filter row by multiply ids. Here is query:

```
select distinct `storage_file`.*, `storage_tag`.`id` as `tid` from `storage_file` 
inner join `storage_file_tag` on `storage_file`.`id` = `storage_file_tag`.`storage_file_id` 
inner join `storage_tag` on `storage_tag`.`id` = `storage_file_tag`.`storage_tag_id`
where `storage_file`.`user_id` = 17 and `storage_file`.`deleted_at` is null and 
`storage_tag`.`id` IN(13,17);
```

So the result is without group by statement is:

[image]

So.. I need result only with two records which contain tid 13 and 17
And when i replace "IN(13,17)" with `storage_tag`.`id` = 13 AND `storage_tag`.`id` = 17 - i get no records at all

How can i write subquery which will work like `a` + `b` but not `a` OR `b` ?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: The question is closed.

Comment: It is not closed & hasn't been. What do you mean?

Comment: This is unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.
This will be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. [ask]

Comment: [MySQL Select Multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3749933/3404097) 
  [SQL query that gives distinct results that match multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1202668/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
... AND id IN (11,22)
```

with

```
... AND ( id = 11 OR id = 12)
```

You need the parentheses because WHERE operator precedence rules are very simple.

Of course,

```
... AND id = 11 AND id = 12
```

never returns anything because the id cannot have two different values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you do exactly but it seams, that the distinct is not working as you expect, because you select "*" from storage_file, as there are different values in the columns of storage_file, the result is distincted but over all selected columnns and so more the two are selected.

Comment: distinct or not - nothing changes

Comment: @mindsupport, that's what I told, you should remove the * from your selected fields and only select the ID